# File associations irrecoverably break when the associated program is moved

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I want to open .pde files with processing. I can select to open with processing:

[image]

The thing is, I unzipped processing in a disorganised folder. I want to organise my folder, so I need to move processing. Now processing does not appear on the list.

[image]

I click on Browse… and select where I moved processing to, and click Open.

[image]

Nothing happens.

[image]

It should come up on the list, shouldn't it?

Comment: This has been like this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following preparation might be necessary:

Start the registry editor `regedit.exe`:

Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` and 
find your .exe name.

Navigate under its name to `shell>open>command`.

In the `Default` entry change its location to the actual location of the executable, hit okay and then try and reassociate the file type as you have tried.

(from [code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=247](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=247))